# Is there a clang-snapshot?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, gcc, llvm

I've just discovered the wonderful [gcc-snapshot](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/gcc-snapshot) package for Ubuntu. I don't see a clang-snapshot or llvm-snapshot package though. Is there an equivalent for clang?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a later version of clang installed on a regular basis you might want to add one of the [PPAs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=clang) on LaunchPad e.g. [this](https://launchpad.net/~h-rayflood/+archive/llvm) one or [this](https://launchpad.net/~georgekola/+archive/clang) one.

Once you have the PPA added to your `/etc/apt` resources, the package can update the package with the normal system update/upgrade just like `gcc-snapshot` would do.

These PPAs are normally the latest, which means not always stable versions of the software. gcc-snapshot is AFAIK somewhat more conservative, being a later version of gcc at the time of release of the Ubuntu version you are using, (but which was not used to compile the system itself).